# Why does CURL show that the EC2 instance is serving files but cannot access it via Public IP?

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2

I have been trying to get a React/Node application deploying on AWS EC2 using NGINX but can't seem to get the public DNS to load anything.

However, when I `curl localhost` and the port that I am running my Node app on `curl localhost:3001`, it seems to output what I am expecting. But I figured at least my static files should load when I hit the public DNS.

I have attached my conf file here. From my understanding, this should serve the static file at the root. I have also attached my inbound rules with HTTP port and TCP port for my backend being open.

Thanks for any guidance.

**/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf**

```
server {
    #listen​       80;
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name  _;

    access_log /home/ubuntu/client/server_logs/host.access.log main;

    location / {
        root   /home/ubuntu/client/deploy;
        index  index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri /index.html;
        add_header X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN;
        add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
        add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
        add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains;";
    }

    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    server_tokens off;

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny  all;
    }

}
```

**Here are my security rules**

[image: Security]

Comment: Does `public_ip:3001` work? Port 80 probably isn't working because you need to open it up in the firewall on the Linux server.

Comment: what do you mean by "NGINX but can't seem to get the public DNS to load anything" Are you getting timeouts? Do you see an entry in access log?

Comment: @MarkB 3001 isn't working either. I have 80, 443 open via UFW

Comment: @SathyajithBhat Navigating to the public_ip just infinite loop loads till it times out.

Comment: We don't see how the backend server mapping is configured (from nginx 80 to nodejs 3001). As well - what do you mean by the `infinite loop`? Do you get redirects? What does curl returns when requesting a public address?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check the communication between the nginx and your application. Before that try to `curl localhost:80`. If this returns the nginx page then atleast with the public DNS, this page must be loaded. If not run `sudo service nginx status` and check.

On the other hand, are you using load balancer with your setup?

The connection has timed out could also be due to wrong port address being requested too.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I was able to figure out that it was actually my production build frontend that was messed up.